# Crystal Reports - Crosstab average columns as new column called "GPA"

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm fairly new to Crystal Reports but getting better at some of the more advanced features.

I have a report I'm building out that has a simple crosstab - The rows display communities, the columns display categories, and the contents display the averages of these scores.

What I am needing to do is create a new column that calculates an average in a specific order - please see the photo.

[photo:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYyU4.png)

So basically, GPA = AVG(AVG(1),2,3)

I have this set up in crystal reports like this:
[crystal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmSAw.png)

I am very unfamiliar with advanced calculations - how do I create a column off to the right that would calculate the GPA in that order for every row of the report?

I've made sure that headers match between the screen capped Excel file and the columns displayed in Crystal reports.

I just purchased and started using crystal reports a few months ago - it is whatever the current version is (2020?)